# Calling web service from Windows Form and jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, winforms, wcf, web-services

I have an existing web WCF web service which can be called by a Windows form via a proxy.

I wish to also be able to call this service from jQuery.

I am following the following article: http://www.codemag.com/Article/1308041

However, I am stuck because the article says to add the following code to the web.config of the service:

```
<services>
  <service
      behaviorConfiguration="ProductServiceBehavior"
      name="ProductServiceHost.ProductService">
    <endpoint
      address=""
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="ProductServiceHost.IProductService" />
  </service>
</services>
```

My config file already has this for my service:

```
<service 
    behaviorConfiguration="MyApp.EndPoint.Services.TrainingServiceBehavior"    
    name="MyApp.EndPoint.Services.TrainingService">
  <endpoint 
    address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
    contract="MyApp.EndPoint.Services.Interface.ITrainingService" 
    name="wsHttp" 
    bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfiguration">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

I've tried replacing the binding with the basicHttpBinding, but I then get errors when calling the service from my Windows form, such as "The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type."

Should my service have both of the above bindings?

Basically, my changes fail at the step: You should run your existing application at this point to ensure that everything still works.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I added the following to the config file:

```
  <service
      behaviorConfiguration="MyApp.EndPoint.Services.TrainingServiceBehavior"
      name="MyApp.EndPoint.Services.TrainingService">
    <endpoint
      address=""
      binding="basicHttpBinding"
      contract="MyApp.EndPoint.Services.Interface.ITrainingService" />
  </service>
```

I also added the following decoration:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

However, my Windows form app now gets the following error when it calls the service:

The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

The error is presumably because I have two services in the config file with the same name.  If I give the new service a new name, would I have to create a new method?

I'm trying to use the same method, but this seems to be impossible.

Comment: You should not have two services in your config. You need one service  (you already have that name=`MyApp.EndPoint.Services.TrainingService`) having multiple endpoints. Your service has two endpoints (an endpoint having `address=""` and an endpoint having `address="mex"`). For jquery w'll have to add a new endpoint having `address="Web"`. The details of that endpoint are described in the article you linked. What I would do in your case? Start with the configuration that worked (test your form), add the new endpoint and behavior as described (test your form) try to use new endpoint with jquery.

Comment: Thanks vererik - that's got me some way along the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can leave your current configuration as it is. The changes made in the article are made to a very basic configuration in order to make the configuration of the existing service explicit (by stating the binding, the contract and the behavior). Your configuration already states the service explicit.

What you should do is add a new configuration for jquery to use as described in the article: add a new behavior and add a new endpoint.

Comment: Can I still use the same method for both? The article says to add a decoration for use by jQuery (my service accepts a parameter).